# Asynchronously running long running tasks in Elixir

Tags: asynchronous, task, elixir

I have a module that saves data in csv format which takes a relative long time depending on the data size. What is the Elixir way to accomplish this asynchronously? I tried using Agent, but the process times out.

[image]

```
defmodule FinReporting.Export_CSV do
    alias FinReporting.DistributeRepo
    alias FinReporting.InterfaceMdl
    import Ecto.Query

    def start_link do
        Agent.start_link(fn -> HashDict.new end, name: __MODULE__)
    end

    def export do
        Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn dict -> 

                                    export_sub()    
                                end)
    end

    defp export_sub do
        file = File.open!("test.csv",[:write, :utf8])
        IO.puts("===> CSV export of NGInterface file started.")
        DistributeRepo.all(from entry in InterfaceMdl, limit: 100000, select: %{ field1: entry.field1, amount: entry.amount})
                |>Enum.map(fn(entry)-> %{entry|amount: Decimal.to_string(entry.amount)}end) 
                |> Enum.map(fn(m) -> [m.field1, m.amount] end) 
                |> CSV.encode 
                |> Enum.each(&IO.write(file, &1))

        IO.puts("===> CSV export of NGInterface file completed.")
        _ = File.close(file) 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a custom timeout using the third argument to `Agent.update`. You can pass an integer specifying the number of milliseconds, e.g. `60000` for one minute, or `:infinity` for infinite timeout.

```
Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn dict -> export_sub() end, 60000)
```

But, `Agent.update` waits for the function to complete executing, which is not what you want.

You want `Task` and specifically `Task.async/1`.

```
Task.async(fn -> export_sub() end)
```

This will return a `Task` struct that you can wait on later in your application using `Task.await` or ask for its status using `Task.yield`. All this and more is explained in great detail in [the documentation of Task](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html).